# Fibonacci and Harmonic

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, harmonic-numbers

Here is a cute series that I came across and cannot seem to tackle at all.

**Question:** Calculate

$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}$$

where $F_n$ denotes the $n$ -th Fibonacci number and $\mathcal{H}_n^{(s)}$ denotes the $n$ - th harmonic number of order $s$.

What techniques would one use to evaluate it? Should we invoke the Beta function for the binomial? I don't have any ideas on the problem!!

The answer is claimed to be $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi ^{4}}{375\sqrt{5}}$. I have not checked numerically though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One may just use Ramanujan's identity
$$
\arcsin^4\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac32 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k^2}\right\}\frac{x^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}, \qquad |x|\le2, \tag1
$$ proved by Berndt ([Ramanujan’s Notebooks Part 1 p. 263](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan's%20Notebooks%20I.pdf)) then recalling that
$$
F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-(1-\varphi)^{n}}{\sqrt 5},\qquad \varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2,
$$ one gets

> $$
> \mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{2\arcsin^4\left(\dfrac {\sqrt{\varphi}}2\right)-2\arcsin^4\left(\dfrac {\sqrt{1-\varphi}}2\right)}{3\sqrt 5} \tag2
> $$

giving $\mathcal{S}\ne\dfrac{2\pi^{4}}{375\sqrt{5}}$, we have
$$
\mathcal{S} = 0.06085736037597791544248567 \cdots
$$ and$$
\dfrac{2\pi^{4}}{375\sqrt{5}} = 0.2323342391237277 \cdots.
$$

Comment: How do you remember this identity of Ramanujan?? He found so many identities that one can only remember a few famous ones. +1

Comment: (+1) I did not know of that Ramanujan's identity. Thank you!!

Comment: pretty nice $(+1)$